# Excel VBA Copy a chart and paste it in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, charts, copy

I have a Workbook with several worksheets. In the worksheet called "Summary", I have a chart that the values on yaxis changes will change in each loop. Before my loop goes to the next step, I want copy the chart and paste it as image in another worksheet. However, with my actual code, there is an error "(800401d0) THE SPECIFIED DIMENSION IS NOT VALID FOR THE CURRENT CHART TYPE". See part of my code related to try copy and paste de chart.

```
Sheets("Summary").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Copy
Sheets("Scene 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B28").PasteSpecial
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid using `Activate`, that would be preferable, but if you are willing to stick with your current approach, you could use something like this :

```vb
Sheets("Summary").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Copy
Sheets("Scene 1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B28").Activate
Activesheet.Paste
```

If you are willing to improve your code perfomance and avoid potential errors, you could use something like this :

```vb
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("Book9") 'Change this to the name of your workbook or ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Summary")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Scene 1")
    
    Dim chrt1 As ChartObject
    Set chrt1 = ws1.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
    
    'We copy the chart
    chrt1.Copy
    ws2.Paste
    
    'We use the fact that the chart we just pasted is the last added, so the number of charts will be the index of our newly pasted chart
    Dim chrt2 As ChartObject
    Set chrt2 = ws2.ChartObjects(ws2.ChartObjects.Count)
    
    'We copy the name and position of the original chart
    chrt2.Name = chrt1.Name
    chrt2.Top = chrt1.Top
    chrt2.Left = chrt1.Left
```